# Programming an Equalizer App for Android

Tags: android, equalizer

I want to use my One X to play music on my hifi-system. Because the soundquality of the loudspeakers is not that perfect I need to equalize them.

The most players only support about 5 bands but I want more.

Now I want to write my own App. Is there a way to programm the equalizer as "standalone" so that i can run an other music app but change the audiooutput with my eq app?

With API 9 there's already an eq class with that I can possibly make a .. 10  to 20 band eq (i  hope i can control that with my fingers :>) but I don't want to programm a whole music player if it's not necessary.

As far as I can understand there is that "getAudioSessionId()" I need to know to change the audiooutput, but can i get that SessionId outside the "musicplayer-app"?

Comment: Where you got equalizer class which support 10 to 20 band equalizer? Please reply to this in comment.